# Can a resident of Belgium trade US stocks with Interactive Brokers?

Tags: stock-exchanges

I live in Belgium and I would like to trade US stocks. I would like to sign up with Interactive Brokers.  Would it then be possible to trade US stocks?

Comment: IB offers trading in over 200 countries.  Contact them and see what they have to offer you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Interactive Brokers supports Belgium. And, yes, they trade U.S. stocks.

You can find out from [Stockbrokers.com](https://www.stockbrokers.com/guides/internationaltrading) which brokers support Belgium.

You have a choice between:

- Interactive Brokers
- Charles Shwab
- TradeStation
- Firsttrade
- SogoTrade
- Lightspeed
- ChoiceTrade

I recommend that you read reviews of all of them before choosing. E.g. Interactive Brokers has a $30 inactivity fee each month, but it has a very low fee per share. Choose one that is suitable for your trading needs.